# volumes in docker run Vs. docker-compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, containers, devops

env: I am using Docker for Mac

in my docker-compose file:

```
   client:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
```

this works and maps the 'client' directory on my mac in the current directory to the 'app' directory in the container.

But when I try running the same via docker run

```
docker run -v ./client:/app -v /app/node_modules --name clientcont clientimage
```

this gives me error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create ./client: "./client" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed
```

Now, I agree that '/' is the character causing the problem. I tried '.client' also. Same issue. The only that thing works is giving the absolute path.

And if I only use *client:/app*, that will map the docker volume 'client' on docker VM host (not my  Mac) to 'app' in the container. But that's not the requirement.

My query is: **shouldn't there be consistency between docker run and docker-compose on how these volumes are used? If one thing works in docker-compose, shouldn't  it work the same way via docker run also?**

Comment: Try using the absolute/full path of the folder named client instead of relative path.

Comment: `docker run -v` only accepts an absolute path.  There are a couple of small syntax differences between Compose and the standard Docker CLI like this.